Como configurar tests en fast api para que se ejecuten sobre la base de datos configurada para tests?
Estoy usando fast api, mongoDB, pytest. Me está pasando que al ejecutar los tests estos se estan ejecutando apuntando a mi base de datos principal y no a la que se debe configurar para la ejecucion de los tests. Esto esta provocando que se llene mi base de datos del dia a dia con todo lo que generan los tests.
Comparto el codigo de mi archivo conftest.py:
import asyncio

import httpx
import pytest
import pytest_asyncio
from asgi_lifespan import LifespanManager

from ..app import app
from ..controllers.enterprise import create_enterprise
from ..controllers.user_dashboard import create_user_dashboard
from ..controllers.users import create_user
from ..database import motor_client, db_clonia
from ..models.enterprise import EnterpriseDB
from ..models.user_dashboard import UserDashboardDB, TypeUserDashboard
from ..models.users import UserDB
from ..utils import get_password_hash

name_db_test = 'clonia_test'
db_clonia_test = motor_client[name_db_test]


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def event_loop():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    yield loop
    loop.close()


@pytest_asyncio.fixture(autouse=True, scope="session")
async def create_test_database():
    app.dependency_overrides[db_clonia] = db_clonia_test
    yield
    await motor_client.drop_database(name_db_test)


@pytest_asyncio.fixture(scope="session")
async def test_client():
    async with LifespanManager(app):
        async with httpx.AsyncClient(app=app, base_url="http://test") as test_client:
            yield test_client


@pytest_asyncio.fixture(autouse=True, scope="session")
async def user_to_login():
    password = 'password'
    hashed_password = get_password_hash(password)
    enterprise_db = EnterpriseDB(name='enterprise')
    enterprise = await create_enterprise(enterprise_db)
    user = UserDashboardDB(username='test',
                           first_name='Test',
                           last_name='Test',
                           email='test@test.online',
                           hashed_password=hashed_password,
                           type=TypeUserDashboard.admin,
                           enterprise=enterprise)
    await create_user_dashboard(user)

